# Selenium Grid TestCase distribution issue

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run the selenium testcases in the grid.My hub is connected to 2 selenium nodes. While I am trying to run in selenium grid out of 4 test cases sometimes 2 test cases are running on 2 nodes.. and rest of test cases I am getting driver Initialization Error Issue...

The sample TestNG XML is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" > 
    <suite name="ProductionSanity" parallel="tests" verbose="1">
            <test   name="aa1"   >
            <parameter name="customer" value="aa1" />
            <classes>
                <class name="com.test.ProdsanitySearch1" />
                <class name="com.test.ProdsanitySearch11" />
            </classes>
        </test>
        <test  name="Gemes"  >
            <parameter name="customer" value="aa2" />
            <classes>
                class name="com.test.ProdsanitySearch2" />
                <class name="com.test.ProdsanitySearch22" />

            </classes>
        </test>
    </suite>
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

```
public ThreadLocal<WebDriver> m_driverForThread = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>() {
    @Override
    protected WebDriver initialValue() {
        WebDriver driver = null;

        driver = loadDesktopDriver();

        return driver;
    }
};
protected static WebDriver loadDesktopDriver() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = null;
    driver = getNewDriver(m_browser, "", "", m_context);
    return driver;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static WebDriver getNewDriver(String browserName, String browserVersion, String platform,
        ITestContext context) {
    switch (driverType) {
        case CHROME:
            return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(m_gridUrl), desiredCapabilities);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on what you say, this seems to be more of an issue related to Java Code than TestNG. Could you update your question with the class where you instantiate browser drivers?

Comment: @Barney   I have added the sample piece of code how I am initializing  the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here:
a) You are missing thread-count attribute in your suite.xml. 
b) After your tests run the browser is unable to fall back into the pool. so you will have to start your hub and node accordingly.
c) Can you add full exception message here.

Comment: Caused by: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Session [(null externalkey)] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.
Active sessions are[ab9c2298-8c8d-4034-97d6-6d575e452927 (int. key, remote not contacted yet.), d0778531-4f53-4321-9a00-da9ce848e296 (int. key, remote not contacted yet.), c186407c-1838-4ff0-a7c9-79d8f32e90fe (int. key, remote not contacted yet.)]
 at org.openqa.grid.internal.ActiveTestSessions.getExistingSession(ActiveTestSessions.java:110)

Comment: Currently  2 nodes are connected to HUB.

Comment: Would you be able to create a small project which reproduce this issue and share the project on github